# I cant add PPA in Ubuntu , nothing works

Tags: apt, ppa

When I try to add a ppa in Ubuntu 18.04, for example,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:numix/ppa
```

it freezes and nothing works.

After a long time-pressed Ctrl+c, It just returned these connection errors [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eO62o.png)

Comment: Is there any output in the terminal after that? Does Ctrl-C or D, or ctrl-alt-[F1 through F8] or any REISUB / "magic" commands work?

Comment: Yes   here the error, https://imgur.com/a/6DiCVBu , I think it's used to python sockets , i have already installed python in my system, nothing works

Comment: The image you posted does not seem to be the complete error output. Generally, we ask folks here to post properly formatted text instead of images of text. Please add new information to your Question instead of a comment.

Comment: Exact same here. Started a couple of weeks ago.